# How to change the settings logo in Action Bar in Android?

Tags: android, xml, menu

I want to change the `Settings` logo to a `Search` logo. I tried doing the following changes in the xml but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone suggest me what to do?

My xml is as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_minus"
     android:title="@android:string/search_go"/>

 </menu>
```

Comment: add android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_some_image"

Comment: the icon doesn't change

Comment: try android:showAsAction="always" after changing the drawable icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Go to : https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

2) Download "Action Bar Icon Pack"

3) Put ic_action_search in your drawable directory

4) Then : `android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"`

if it doesn't work try : `your_app_name:showAsAction="always"`

As you can read in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) :

> Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace
>   defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML
>   attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do
>   not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use
>   your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the
>   support library.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you ar using action bar

```
<item     
    android:id="@+id/grid_default_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" 
/>

<!-- other items or whatever  -->
```

In your activity

```
@Override 
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.grid_default, menu); 
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.grid_default_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryListener);

}

final private OnQueryTextListener queryListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {       

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

      //Logic
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {            
      //Logic
        return false;
    }
};
```